# How do I using Mongo aggregation to get the total "page views" for each group of days

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, database

I have tried for a few days now to come up with a working aggregate but I'm just not getting it.

I have a collection that looks similar to the following.

```
_id: ObjectId("52672ca368a56f481d000045"),  
totalviews: 5, 
views: [ 
  {date: ISODate("2013-10-23T01:55:47Z") },
  {date: ISODate("2013-10-23T01:55:50Z") },
  {date: ISODate("2013-10-23T23:31:08Z")},
  {etc.}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get a total number of views for each day so I can display a list of dates (from "views") and the total for those days.

Can someone show me how this can be done?

Thank you

Edit - Below Code Works Correctly
Here is the php code for the solution provided in case it helps someone else:

```
$ops = array(
array('$unwind' => '$views'),
array('$project' => array('date'=>array(
    'day'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$views.date'),
    'month'=>array('$month'=>'$views.date'),
    'year'=>array('$year'=>'$views.date'))
)),
array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$date','views'=>array('$sum'=>1))) 
);

$data = $collection->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output. Right now your question is not clear. Do you want views by day per document or views by day per collection? You should also show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
db.foo.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$views"},    
    {$project: {date: {
        day: {$dayOfMonth: "$views.date"},
        month: {$month: "$views.date"},
        year: {$year: "$views.date"},
    }}},
    {$group: {_id: {id: "$_id", date: "$date"}, views: {$sum: 1}}}
 )
```

If you want total number of views per day for collection replace group phase with this one:

```
{$group: {_id: "$date", views: {$sum: 1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was missing how to break up the date correctly.